# Is setting Active Directory groups on NFS mounts supported?

Tags: linux, permissions, nfs

My current CentOS 6.8 setup utilizes Winbind to authenticate and authorize users using Active Directory. When I try to set group ownership on a folder or file that is located on an NFS mount, it fails with the error "operation not permitted".

So I check to make sure that it can resolve the group ID, its membership, and that user1 (the active user) is part of the group:

```
$ getent group testgroup
testgroup:*:298341:user1,user2
```

Everything checks out.  So I suspect that it's an NFS issue.  So I try this on a non-NFS mount (e.g. `/`, or `/tmp`) and it works fine (i.e. I can chgrp on /test to testgroup).

This indicates that the following nsswitch are fine (these are the only altered entries):

```
passwd:     files winbind
shadow:     files winbind
group:      files winbind
```

I check the mount settings to make sure it's using sec=sys (the default) but it's not explicitly set.

```
rw,vers=3,proto=tcp,hard,intr,retrans=2,wsize=32768,rsize=32768,sloppy
```

What am I missing?  Is this even supported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a limitation of NFS SYS_AUTH where the protocol is limited to transmitting 16 groups.  The fix is to use GSSAPI or to modify the NFS server to use the --manage-gid-lookup option.